# The value expression for the texttrun 'Textbox86.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30451] Name 'IFF' is not declared

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am newbie and designing SSRS. Used Row Groups(DistrictName,StoreName,Employee_Name) and Column Groups (MetricsOrder,MetricsName,Year,Month).

Finally it prints 2 total value.

First it prints District Total and another one is the overall total. I need to Check some condition and the value may differ upon the condition.

Here is my expression. Checking weather is it current month. If so, multiply SUM values with RR(Parameter). If not, just print the SUM value

```
IFF((MONTH(TODAY())=Fields!Month.Value),Sum(Fields!MetricValue.Value)*Parameters!RR.Value,Sum(Fields!MetricValue.Value)
```

When i run the Report im getting the below error.

> An error occured during local report processing. The definition of the
>   report '/Report11TRIAL2 is invalid'. The value expression for the
>   texttrun 'Textbox86.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error:
>   [BC30451] Name 'IFF' is not declared.

Could any one help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the expression should be:

```
IIF((MONTH(TODAY())=Fields!Month.Value),Sum(Fields!MetricValue.Value)*Parameters!RR.Value,Sum(Fields!MetricValue.Value)
```

IIF, not IFF.